# On topic question closed for being off topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

This was a question I asked some time ago on this site that got closed. I still haven't found any satisfying information regarding it.

[Company or website logo as the search result image / Google+ profile](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35819)

I'm not new to StackExchange as I have many active accounts and I did think carefully about this question and where to ask it.

Even when I review it now, I still think it's valid and not off-topic as suggested. It has also been upvoted twice and my comment about it being closed been upvoted twice.

The description of this site has be believe that this question is not off-topic

> Pro Webmasters - Stack Exchange is for professional and enthusiast
>   webmasters. If your question generally covers the operation of
>   websites which you control, then you’re in the right place to ask your
>   question!

Then I see this meta site and realise there are a lot of questions from those wondering why their question was closed. Upon reading them, perhaps there are valid reasons, but would still have me think that some of them where closed rather abruptly, and whether there are ways to improve this process on this site, as I've never noticed it as much on other SE sites.

Comment: Agreed. I don't see it. There are plenty of other Google+ questions that have been accepted and answered, including about the authorship feature.

Comment: Thanks for the support, interestingly it's now my highest rated question out of roughly 40 questions I've asked across different SE sites

Comment: I came here to ask the same thing about [my HTML5 Video question](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/924/why-was-my-question-on-html5-video-closed-and-moved-to-stack-overflow) being moved to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was some confusion caused by a lack of [seo](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo) on the question. I like your edits, and based on the meta response here, I'm comfortable reopening the question. Thank you for your patience!